# Why won't one of my rails apps go into the production env when its deployed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, mina

I have a few rails apps that I have on a single VPS. I am using nginx, passenger, mysql and rails 4 for all of them. Two of the apps are working fine in the production ENV, but one of my apps is not switching to production. It just stays in development. I use mina for deployment. I've been pulling my hair out over this trying to figure out the reason why.

In my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I have

```
 passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.in$
 passenger_ruby /home/ME/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
 passenger_app_env production;
```

and my server blocks for each of my apps are identical like this (replacing "mysite" with the respective app names)

```
server {
    listen 80;
   # listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /var/www/mysite.com/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? I don't think Ive changed anything in the apps code, but can anyone think of something that I may have altered? Are there any rails files I could have changed that would be causing this?
Thanks.

**Update 7/13/14**
So i've completely removed the files from my app on the server and re deployed fresh, and Im still having the problem. I am using [mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/) to deploy my apps, and I ran `mina deploy --trace` and it says its doing `$ RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_GROUPS=assets`. I also added a test to my footer (`Rails.env.production?`) and it is returning false. Thanks for any help.

**Update 7/14/14**
So to test if it was my server or my code, I ran `rails server -e production` on my development machine. I still have the same problem with the `Rails.env.production?` returning false. So its clearly something in my rails code. Ihave no clue what I could have altered though still.

Comment: Have you restarted nginx since making changes to the app? What makes you think your app isn't running in the production environment?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have restarted nginx. I know its not in production because I have a debug line in my footer that only shows up if `RAILS_ENV == 'development'`, and it still is showing when I visit it on my server. I have the same line in all of my apps, and its is preforming correctly in them, so its something with this app.

Answer (score 0):

So stupid me, i figured it out. I should have posted the code I had in my footer

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env = "development" %>
<%= sanitize("<b>Ruby</b>: #{RUBY_VERSION} <b>Rails:</b> #{Rails.version}") if Rails.env == "development" %>
<%= Rails.env.production? %>
```

The problem clearly was that I was assigning `Rails.env` to "development" instead of checking if IT WAS equal with "==". I changed that and now all is good.